# .net to the core

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

An [entity-framework-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) tag was recently created. Tag [asp.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) was created some 8 months ago.

I can see a pattern here: do we really want a -core version of every single .net-related technology tag?

Any ideas? Reasons to keep them around?

Comment: Can you explain this for someone who doesn't know the .net world? What is this `-core` thing? How does this differ from normal?

Comment: @SimonForsberg it's a version of the [tag:.net] framework that eats Java's lunch and runs on iOS and Linux ;-)

Answer (score 17):

I'm going to defend *all* these tags, because after thinking about it, I think they do provide value.

First and foremost: [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) / [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) are not universal/compatible. Just because something works in [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) does not mean it works in [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core), and vice-versa. These tags are two *completely separate* frameworks, so I agree with creating a [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) tag. Now, you can write code that works in both, but we're talking about a [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) vs. [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) situation: they're *not* guaranteed to be the same.

This means that, by definition, [asp.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) is *not* interchangeable for [asp.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net): a person can have expertise in one but *not* the other. This means applying [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) to an [asp.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) question *is wrong*, the [asp.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) technology is *quite* different.

Second, if we create [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) and burn the other two, we're encouraging tagging [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) alongside [asp.net-mvc-4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4), which is semantically incorrect. [Microsoft calls ASP.NET on .NET Core *just* ASP.NET Core](https://dusted.codes/understanding-aspnet-core-10-aka-aspnet-5-and-why-it-will-replace-classic-aspnet), we should too. The [asp.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) runtime *is not compatible* with [asp.net-mvc-x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-x), it's a different runtime, with different features, which means someone like me (who follows all the [asp.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) tags) will be *even more confused* than currently.

You should have *no more than* **one** .NET tag, *no more than* **one** ASP.NET tag, and *no more than* **one** Entity-Framework tag. Whichever of them applies *best* is what you should use.

Third, the [entity-framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework) and [entity-framework-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) [are so *astoundingly different*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/) that it would be wildly inappropriate to use [entity-framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework) [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) to define them.

Realistically, we should proceed as follows:

1. Edit questions to appropriately tag; if the question is on [asp.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core), then we should remove the [asp.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) tag if present, and add [asp.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) if not present, and adjust any related tags ([entity-framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework) » [entity-framework-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core), [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) » [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core), etc.).
2. Create the [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) tag and replace the [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag with it where appropriate.
3. When it comes to:

   > EF-Core is currently used in conjunction with uwp, which implies .net-core, and with asp.net-core, which also implies .net-core.

   I'm *not* sure I see the problem there. We also use [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) with [winforms](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winforms) and [asp.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net), should we not do that either? The purpose of tags is to group a question in *with similar questions* be it for following purposes, analytics, whatever — the tags should be *self-contained*. I follow all the .NET tags, including all 5 [asp.net-mvc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) tags, but that may *not* be the case for everyone, some users have *no* experience with .NET Core, so an answer they provide *can be very incorrect* — this means they probably *don't* want to follow [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core), and as such [asp.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) or [entity-framework-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core), they're different ecosystems.

I really don't think anything else is required — this is just like the [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) / [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) or [angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular) / [angular-2+](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular-2%2b) situations, a *complete* restart of the framework.

---

Personally, instead of burninating these, let's burn [asp.net-mvc-2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-2), [asp.net-mvc-3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3), [asp.net-mvc-4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4) and [asp.net-mvc-5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-5). Why the heck do we have a tag for every version of ASP.NET MVC?

---

## Tl;dr;

Create the new tag, leave the others present, edit questions with both '.NET' and '.NET-Core' to one or the other; edit questions with both 'Entity-Framework' and 'Entity-Framework-Core' with one or the other; edit questions with both 'ASP.NET' and 'ASP.NET-Core' with one or the other;

Comment: Now *that* is an answer =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I try. ;) I actually upvoted your answer, then Mast mentioned this in chat and I thought harder about it and decided to write a new answer. :)

Comment: I went ahead and removed [tag:.net] and [tag:asp.net-mvc] tags from [tag:asp.net-core]-tagged questions.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Awesome! I'm thinking we should create `.net-core` for the more general `.net-core` stuff (whatever it may be), this way the users could follow `.net-core` *specifically*, or `asp.net-core`, `entity-framework-core`, etc. I *also* think we should burn `asp.net-mvc-2`-`asp.net-mvc-5`, there's *no* reason to have all four of those tags *along with* `asp.net-mvc`.

Comment: Just an FYI, Angular is Angular 2+. You're probably thinking of AngularJS. I have also requested [tag:angular] to not be synonyms with [tag:angular.js], [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8469).

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yeah, I was thinking what you mentioned (which goes to further prove the confusion) :).

Comment: Why would anyone use [tag:.net-core]? That would be like using a tag [tag:elf-binary]. What's relevant for reviewing code is the library API, so surely [tag:.net-standard] would be the useful tag for distinguishing code which is specific to .Net Framework from code which is compatible with .Net Core?

Comment: @PeterTaylor The problem with that is how Microsoft chose to name and market it. And *every now and then* they refer to `.net-standard` as the `.net-core` stuff. The main .NET framework does **not** share compatibilities with .NET Core, in fact, so the `.net-core` tag would still be sensible there. (It's not like `elf-binary` because it's *forward and reverse incompatible* with the .NET Framework 1.0-4.6.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*The main .NET framework does **not** share compatibilities with .NET Core, in fact*". For example, .Net Standard 1.6 is compatible with .Net Framework 4.6.1 and .Net Core 1.0. Is your point that [tag:.net-core] might be useful for the one or two people who might want a review of code which uses namespaces under `Microsoft.NETCore`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, my point is that when developing for `.net-core` things are *very* different. For example, in .NET core I seem to recall Entity Framework not having a .FirstOrDefault(), instead it has .SingleOrDefault.

Comment: Ah, so your point is that [tag:.net-core] would be appropriate for questions which *also* have [tag:entity-framework-core] or [tag:asp.net-core]? If so, I don't think that comes through very clearly. To what questions would point 2 of the answer apply when point 1 does not?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well .NET core/standard is intentionally cross-platform, among other things. I support the diverged tag for those reasons as well. But yet, I think using `.net-core` as a replacement for `asp.net-core` and `entity-framework-core` is a bad idea. I also appreciate you bringing the discussion up, I'll try to incorporate it in this answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I propose we create a [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) tag for the overarching framework, and replace:

- [entity-framework-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) with [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core)[entity-framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework)
- [asp.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) with [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core)[asp.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net)

Comment: Why? Sure, it saves a couple of tags in the long run, but how does this improve the situation based on the guidelines of when a tag is useful or not?

Comment: @Mast because `[.net-core]` is the semantically correct thing to do. [tag:asp.net-core] is already misused alongside with [tag:asp.net-mvc], which is totally redundant (the old WebForms framework simply doesn't run on .net core). Or is that a bad reason?

Comment: I don't know. But both tags, [tag:entity-framework-core] and [tag:asp-net-core], seem to target a specific framework. So turning them into combination tags doesn't sound logical to me.

Comment: Not sure it's so clear-cut. EF-Core is currently used in conjunction with [tag:uwp], which implies [tag:.net-core], and with [tag:asp.net-core], which *also* implies [tag:.net-core].

Comment: FWIW I'm hoping to see answers *defending* the existence of the tags here =)