# What's your angle on desynonymizing [Angular] and [Angular.js]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

As we should know from "["Angular" (Angular is not Angular.js)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7286)", Angular is not AngularJS - Angular is Angular2+.

Wikipedia also says they're different things:

- [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(application_platform)) - "Angular (commonly referred to as "Angular 2+" or "Angular 2")"; and,
- [AngularJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) -  "AngularJS (commonly referred to as "Angular.js" or "AngularJS 1.X")"

And so I'd like to request that [angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular) is desynonymized with [angular.js](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular.js).

---

I however don't think we should allow an [angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular) tag, as we do not know if 'Angular 2+' will ever become obsolete, and they make, say, 'Angular 5+' the new 'Angular'.

Comment: Given that we're several months later and [angular] is still a synonym of [angular.js] and [angular-js], that the fate of angular vs angular-js is [brought up once more on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8564/23788), and that throughout all these discussions, the rather obvious consensus is that *angular and angular-js aren't the same thing*, I've gone ahead and deleted the synonym, created an actual [tag:angular] tag, and suggested it as a synonym of [tag:angular-2+] - [vote it up/down here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/angular-2%2b/synonyms)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: `angular` and `angular.js` are two different things, therefore not the logical synonyms, therefore de-synonymization is right in my opinion.

---

Looks like there is more than one thing here to think about.

Firstly, in my very humble opinion, **CR.SE should stick to names that are meaningful/accepted in the communities around the specific technologies**. Otherwise, why bother with terminology and vocabulary at all? It means, Angular version 2 and above should be called `Angular`. Everything before v2 is `Angular.js`. This is how we should tag the questions *today*. In other words, *I agree with desynonymization "starting today and going forward"*.

Secondly, we don't really know whether the new terms will appear on Angular's landscape. If they do, **it's fine to reflect these new terms in CR tags, why not?** Is tag proliferation a big deal? Not to me, but more experienced CR Meta users know better.

Lastly, would we like to **dive into revisiting & re-tagging** all the exiting (old) question which say "angular" but mean "angular.js" **for very little benefits?** Why put an effort into this? Just for the consistency? It's okay to have these artifacts that show how Angular-related technologies evolved over time. (In a way, it's similar to Git's idea of not messing up with history). Again, what does the renaming of older questions achieve exactly?

And here's another (not my) idea. We can always take a look at **what does the SO do with these Angular[.js] tags**. I'm not proposing blindly accepting their decision, but at lest enlighten ourselves on what was their thinking process. In addition to that, I believe (have no real stats/data) that on SO it's a bit more important to keep the old questions in a good shape, because the site visitors are much more likely to search for their answer before posing a question. This is very different in CR.SE because it's usually much harder to even formulate a search query when one wants their code to be reviewed -- I bet the site visitor just clicks the "Ask Question" and jumps into formatting his/her code.

Just my five cents.

Comment: FWIW, SO currently has [angularjs] for AngularJS 1.x questions, and [angular] (with synonyms [angular2], [angular4] and [angular4.x]) for Angular 2+. But that's [not a completely unproblematic situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356947/the-angularjs-and-angular-tags-are-constantly-misused-how-can-it-be-improve), since many new users don't realize the difference and just pick one of the tags at random, or even both. Personally, I'd probably prefer [angularjs-1.x] and [angular2+] for clarity.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yeah, the users can always shoot themselves in the foot. Same is true for C/C++, or Python 2/3, or other similar tags, right? Does it mean, those need to be merged too?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that the tags should be merged, just saying that the distinction between "angular" and "angularjs", as currently used on SO, probably isn't clear enough. I suspect there are plenty of new Angular users who have never heard of AngularJS, and just think "oh, there are two Angular tags... well, the one I'm using is a JS framework, so I'd better pick [angularjs]". In any case, even if not ideal, the SO setup is certainly better than what we have here at the moment.

Comment: I don't really understand how the majority of your answer relates to the desynonymization request. It'd also be good if you found the answer to your questions, most of which have been answered before, so that your answer isn't wild speculation.

Comment: @Peilonrayz TL;DR: `angular` and `angular.js` are two different things, therefore not the logical synonym, therefore de-synonymization is right in my opinion. My answer explains the "why"s. Not sure how is that [maybe wordy] explanation is unrelated to the request.

Comment: Your last comment doesn't appear to be related to your answer. Which is a shame, since your last comment is a better answer than your current answer as it stands. It actually answers the question, which your answer doesn't appear to do.